# Why PhoneGap Build includes 3 phonegap.js in Android build?

Tags: cordova, apk, phonegap-build

If I open the .apk built with "PhoneGap Build" service, I find three js files in the app root folder.

```
"phonegap.js"
"cordova-2.7.0.js"
"cordova.js"
```

These files have different filename but identical content.
Why PG Build includes these three files if I reference **phonegap.js** only?

[image: folder structure screenshot]

Comment: Because PG js file is actually different js file across platforms (android, ios, windows 8, bb, etc..), it will attempt to overwrite your PG js file for that platform build and assume what you will name it like above.

Comment: This is not the case: 1) I am inspecting the .apk file (so the packet was **already specialized** for android) - 2) these three files are **identical**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found in the official support forum:
[Duplicates in APK (phonegap.js & cordova.js & cordova-x.x.x.js)](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/duplicates_in_apk_phonegap_js_cordova_js_cordova_x_x_x_js)

> Many users were including the wrong file. Allowing inclusion of any of the above avoided a lot of confusion -- enough to outweigh the footprint of two extra files, in our opinion.

Comment: The forum doesn't mention which of these files is actually the *right* file to include.

Comment: Just include phonegap.js, like in the official samples.
For instance: https://github.com/phonegap-build/pgb-example-console/blob/master/www/index.html

Comment: or cordova.js in these docs: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid_full_example